# Sorry! An unexpected error occurred. Debug: TypeError51

Tags: magento2.4.5, pwa, react, pdp, react-js

We are getting below issue in Venia PWA PDP Page.

Error :

```
Sorry! An unexpected error occurred. Debug: TypeError51 at /RootCmp_PRODUCT__default.1b66b4c414dc44018e9b.js:312:62
```

How to debug what causes the issue ?

[image]